# Iptables. Is there any way to redirect (dnat) a specific (match) packet?

Tags: iptables

Please need your help! I am trying to redirect some specific packet that i marked according to some string, but something goes wrong :( There are my rules...

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 502 -m string --algo bm --hex-string '|06|' -j MARK --set-mark 0x1

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m --mark 0x1 -j DNAT 192.168.1.22:555
```

But i only see the rule number one is working, the second one does not :( Thank you in advance for help of any kind!

Comment: Your rules are full of errors: some generated by your editor and/or cut/paste giving wrong characters, like single quotes; then you have a few missing words in your syntax (for algo, mark, DNAT...). But despite this I can tell you can't do it in this example: You want to NAT an already established TCP connection. For TCP data to transit (and be read by `string`) it's already established. It's too late to do NAT on an established connection. So for your example it's not possible.Could work for UDP. Of course if you explained what you want to do, and not how you want to do it, that would help.

Comment: Thank you for your attention! Yep, now I see errors, I was doing that on ipad (retype), that's why I think. I will try to explain what I would like to do. I have two machines (master, slave) connected by tcp with modbus protocol (port 502). I am trying to be man in the middle with linux machine. I am using arpspoof to do that. Now I would like to ignore all read requests from master to slave, and to redirect all write requests to linux machine. If it is possible to do that with iptables, may be iproute2? Thank you!

Comment: If it's TCP you have to intercept all the flow. As router it's possible with iptables using REDIRECT or TPROXY. Then, you'll have to have a "modbus proxy" that would transmit it to the destination but could alter it to do what you want. You have to edit your question accordingly. But sorry that's about all I'm able to tell about this.

Comment: Thank you A.B for the explanation! Now it’s more clear for me;) I will try to use it...